# Question about fetching only the rows of a table which has a concrete value in a concrete field using Doctrine 1.0

Tags: doctrine, dql

is there anyway to fetch only the rows of a table which has a concrete
value in a concrete field.

For example:

```
$24_people = $table->getFieldAndValue('age', 24);
```

I now i can do it with a query, but wouldn't you find useful this kind
of functions? or maybe is no possible or is not convenient because some
reason ?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
$table->createQuery()->where('age = ?', 24);
```

or:

```
$table->findAllByAge(24);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
$24_people = Doctrine::getTable('People')->findOneByAge(24);
```

See Doctrine magic methods.

http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/06-Working-With-Data